# Call filter() after find() jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to detect wether there is `.product` which css is `display: block;` (visible) in `.calendar-paper` or not.

```js
var $objArr = $('.calendar-paper');
$objArr.each(function(i) {
    var $thisCalendar = $objArr.eq(i);
    if(!$thisCalendar.find('.product').filter(':visible')) {
        // Do something if the content of .calnedar-paper is empty 
    } else {
       
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="calendar-paper">
    <div class="product" style="display: block;">...</div>
    <div class="product" style="display: none;">...</div>
</div>

<div class="calendar-paper">
    <div class="product" style="display: block;">...</div>
</div>
```

And the result shows that even if the `.product` css `display: none`, still run the `else` condition. That's not what I expect. Please explain to me where the logic goes wrong. Thank you.

Comment: "And I can't get the result that I want" — What result *do* you want?

Comment: [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) returns a jQuery object which is always truthy.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry. I just edited my question. Please read it again and please give me a hand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing to find it's length:

```
if($thisCalendar.find('.product').filter(':visible').length) {
```

But I suspect that you wanted to use [:empty selector](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/#empty1) instead of `:visible` selector.

```
if($thisCalendar.find('.product:empty').length) {
```

Comment: This is because just like @str said `filter()` always returns a jQuery object and I will always get true in the if-else condition. So I need to test the length of the object right?